# SQL: Select rows that contain a word

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

The goal is to select all rows that contain some specific word, can be in the beginning or the end of the string and/or surrounded by white-space, should not be inside other word, so to speak.

Here are couple rows in my database:

```
+---+--------------------+
| 1 | string with test   |
+---+--------------------+
| 2 | test string        |
+---+--------------------+
| 3 | testing stringtest |
+---+--------------------+
| 4 | not-a-test         |
+---+--------------------+
| 5 | test               |
+---+--------------------+
```

So in this example, selecting word `test`, should return rows 1, 2 and 5.

Problem is that for some reason, `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... RLIKE '(\s|^)test(\s|$)';` returns 0 rows.

Where am I wrong and maybe, how it could be done better?

**Edit:** Query should also select the row with just a word `test`.

**The answer** to my first question is:
 I haven't escaped special characters, so `\s` should be `\\s`.
Working query: `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... RLIKE '(\\s|^)test(\\s|$)';`. (or just a space `( |^)`/`( |$)`, also works)

Comment: what do you mean by, should not be inside another word?

Comment: @alex067 Selecting `test` should **NOT** return `testing stringtest` and `not-a-test`.

Comment: Here's my trick:  Select * Where ' ' + String + ' ' like '% Test %'.  Adding the space before and after helps match it.

Comment: @JJ32 Yes, but no. This would Not select rows where `test` is in beginning or the end of the string.

Comment: Have you tried it?  If you have Where like ' ' (space) + String + ' ' (space) it gets the beginning because ' ' + 'Test string' is like '% Test % '

Comment: @JJ32 Ahhh, didn't get it the first time, but anyways, `select * from table where ' ' + column + ' ' like '% test %';` returns 0, or I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: You say "whitespace"; could there also be punctuation as a word boundary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you could grab with trailing space and with leading space

```
SELECT * from new_table
where text RLIKE(' test')
union
SELECT * from new_table
where text RLIKE('test ')
```

Comment: Yes! This works, but is there a better way than doing just 2 queries? Like, why my query doesn't work?

Comment: This also works:

`SELECT * FROM new_table 
WHERE text REGEXP ('(^| )test( |$)');`

The Reson why you code dont work is that the Space Escape dident work. Try to type directly the Space :-)

Comment: YES!! So the problem was with escaping the Special Characters. Meaning, `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... RLIKE '(\\s|^)test(\\s|$)';` works!
*Selecting this as correct answer because I got an answer, why my first query didn't work.*

Comment: @MaksTech - _Usually_ it is more efficient to MySQL do multiple things in a single, more complex, query.  In this case, there is a subtle thing that is going on that you would have to code for:  both `SELECT` grabbing the same row.  `UNION` defaults to `UNION DISTINCT` which makes a pass to de-duplicate the output.  Example:  `"test test"`

Answer (score 1):

`REGEXP_INSTR()` function, which's is an extension of the `INSTR()` function, might be used for version 10.0.5+ `case-insensitively` as default :

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
 WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(str, 'TeSt ')>0
    OR REGEXP_INSTR(str, ' tESt')>0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=973585b3baebf4025d5f1dae2e59dfb2)</kbd>

Comment: Yes, this also works, but now I thought about it and forgot to include a case when a in a row there is just a word `test`, which in this case would not be selected.

Answer (score 0):

> `SELECT * FROM ...
>   WHERE ... LIKE 'test';`

This should do the trick.

Comment: I think you needs some `'%test%'`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
   SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... LIKE 
     '%test%';
```

Comment: This would select all rows in my example, including `testing stringtest` and `not-a-test` which are not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundary tests:

Before MySQL 8.0, and in MariaDB:

```
WHERE ... REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]'
```

MySQL 8.0:

```
WHERE ... REGEXP '\btest\b'
```

(If that does not work, double up the backslashes; this depends on whether the client is collapsing backslashes before MySQL gets them.)

Note that this solution will also work with punctuation such as the comma in "foo, test, bar"